# Kivy ids in python code

Tags: python, kivy

main:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class testclass:
    def someth(txt):
        print (txt)
        #how get  access to textinput from begin Screen here?
class BeginScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout =BoxLayout(orientation='vertical',padding=20,spacing=5,)
        self.btn=Label(text=str('Hello'))
        self.layout.add_widget(self.btn)
        self.btn=TextInput(id='test',text='')
        self.layout.add_widget(self.btn)
        self.btn=Button(text='Button!', on_press=testclass.someth('?'))
        # what write in ? to send textinput text to testclass.someth?
        self.layout.add_widget(self.btn)
        self.add_widget(self.layout)
        print(self.layout.ids) #why i have no ids? textinput have id

class TestApp(App):   
    from kivy.config import Config
    Config.set('graphics', 'width', '800')
    Config.set('graphics', 'height', '400')
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(BeginScreen(name='test'))
        return sm
TestApp().run()
```

So how can i access the textinput? I have id='test' but when i printing layouts id is saying i have noone. Why? Someone can explain me what im doing wrong and how can i make it good?

Comment: why are using `self.btn` over and over for declaring your widgets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## from functools import partial

To access the textinput in your external method, you could use partial functions or lambda function.

## self.ids

You are getting None or empty dictionary because you don't have a kv file.

### Note

When your kv file is parsed, kivy collects all the widgets tagged with id’s and places them in this self.ids dictionary type property.

Please refer to my example below for deatils.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from functools import partial


class testclass:
    def someth(*args, txt):
        print(txt)


class BeginScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BeginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', padding=20, spacing=5)
        layout.add_widget(Label(text=str('Hello')))

    # layout.add_widget(TextInput(id='test', text=''))  # id in python+kivy is deprecated
    txtInput = TextInput(text='text input')
    layout.add_widget(txtInput)
    self.ids['test'] = txtInput

    layout.add_widget(Button(text='Button!', on_press=partial(testclass.someth, txt=self.ids.test.text)))
    self.add_widget(layout)

    print("self.ids={}".format(self.ids))
    print("self.ids['test']={}".format(self.ids['test']))
    print("self.ids['test'].text={}".format(self.ids['test'].text))
    print("self.ids.test.text={}".format(self.ids.test.text))
    for key, val in self.ids.items():
        print("key={0}, val={1}".format(key, val))


class TestApp(App):
    from kivy.config import Config
    Config.set('graphics', 'width', '800')
    Config.set('graphics', 'height', '400')

    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(BeginScreen(name='test'))
        return sm

TestApp().run()
```

### Output

[image: Button Pressed]

Comment: I now understand a little more, i have one more question u know why polish letter like łśąć works when i write it on python but on kv files wont looks normal?

Comment: The example does not work anymore (`TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)` at line defining the `id`), any clue?

Comment: @mmj: Coding Kivy 'id' in python has been deprecated. Please check updated solution.

Comment: @ikolim I'm trying to set the id of buttons defined inside a `App` subclass but it seems that `App` does not have the `ids` dictionary, why?

Comment: @mmj: The ids dictionary is only defined in the root, [root widget’s ids dictionary](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html)